# Ubuntu 13.04: Synchronizing an iPhone's contacts and calendar without Ubuntu One

Tags: 13.04, sync, thunderbird, iphone, lightning

What is the best solution to synchronize the contacts and calendar of an iPhone with your local Ubuntu installation?

Note:

- Thunderbird with its Lightning extension currently seems to be the best calendar/contacts solution, so that's what I plan on using.
- The broad global surveillance revelations of the last few weeks have made it clear for me that storing my data "in the cloud" is not a good idea, so I'll also abstain from using Ubuntu One.

Comment: I have been searching for an answer to this for a while now and have not succeeded. The problem seems to be Apples policy of not supporting Linux in any form. I have had to keep windows installed while I wait for a solution, just to run iTunes!

Comment: Just in case there really should be no solution to this: Is there any other (more indirect) way to move contacts/calendar data from one onto the other device and/or vice versa? (I mean without keeping a Windows or Mac machine.)

Comment: Not that I have found, but I keep my fingers crossed.

Comment: Well, with Apple reporting to the NSA, I guess now is the best time to get rid of any remaining Apple stuff, anyways...

Comment: If you want to sync calendar & contacts with any other operating system `Evolution-Data-Server` is your best option.Sync EDS calendar & contacts with online service fruux using [syncevolution](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SyncEvolution). [Fruux](https://fruux.com/) offers caldav & carddav. On iphone add caldav for calendar & carddav for contacts.

Comment: If you want you can sync your data with google and then use KDE Kontact & Calendar or gnome contacts with KDE calendar. An other option is to sync via EDS with TB/Lightning

Comment: @bob - Thanks. As far as Google is concerned, they're working with the NSA and have even lied straight to our faces in their first statement after the Prism news, so they've become a big no-no. I'll give your second suggestion a shot.

Comment: PS: How to get your iPhone contacts out of iTunes, into a .csv file: http://www.trickyways.com/2010/06/how-to-export-iphone-contacts-windows-xp/

Answer (score 0):

I use Funambol on ubuntu to sync Thunderbird (ESR 17) and android since couple of years. Funambol sync-client for Lightning is available at https://maurus.net/resources/funambol/

Comment: That software is "not production ready" - and I see nothing about iPhones.